# Remove XML if no match with CSV file

Tags: xml, file, powershell, csv, match

I have a source XML file and I need to verify if the `AddressType` used in the XML matches any of those defined in a CSV file. If the `AddressType` matches those defined in the app then everything is ok and do nothing else. 
However, if the `AddressType` does NOT match then delete the whole provider from the XML file.

All the `AddressType` codes are stored in a CSV which has got a header line (called `ADDRESS_TYPE`).

```
ADDRESS_TYPE
DR
FIS
HQ
MAIN
NOT_STATED
OP
```

This is my XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="10">
    <OrganisationId>ORG01</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ORGANISATION 01</OrganisationName>
    <Addresses>
      <AddressesRow num="1">
        <AddressId>E25802</AddressId>
        <MainAddress>Y</MainAddress>
        <AddressType>HQ</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
      <AddressesRow num="2">
        <AddressId>E25899</AddressId>
        <MainAddress>N</MainAddress>
        <AddressType>MAIN</AddressType>
        <AddressTypeDesc>Head Office</AddressTypeDesc>
      </AddressesRow>
    </Addresses>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

This sample file has got 2 lines where the `AddressType` matches the CSV file so it should be left untouched. If any of the `AddressTypes` did not match then whole provider needs to be marked for deletion.

```bsh
$File = "C:\Dump\test\edited_file.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $File)

$address_type_csv = Import-Csv "C:\Dump\address_types.csv"

foreach ($row in $address_type_csv) {
    Write-Host "$row" -ForegroundColor White
}

Write-Host $address_type_csv -ForegroundColor White

$field1 = $row.ADDRESS_TYPE
Write-Host "CSV Address Type value = $field1" -ForegroundColor White

$NonMatching = $false
foreach ($UnitRow in $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow) {
    $OrgID = $UnitRow.OrganisationId
    $OrgName = $UnitRow.OrganisationName
    foreach ($AddressRow in $UnitRow.Addresses.AddressesRow) {
        $n = $AddressRow.AddressType
        Write-Host "XML file AddressType is $n" -ForegroundColor White
        if ($field1 -eq $n) {
            echo "MATCH. blabla"
            Write-Host "MATCH. XML value is $n, Address Type $field1" -ForegroundColor White
        } else {
            echo "NO MATCH. XML value is $n, Address Type $field1"    
            Write-Host "NO MATCH. XML value is $n, Address Type $field1" -ForegroundColor White
            $UnitRow.parentNode.RemoveChild($UnitRow) >$null
            $NonMatching = $true
            break
        }
    }
}
if ($NonMatching) {
    $xml.Save("$File")
}
```

At the moment I only seem to be picking up the last row in the CSV file.

```
PS C:\dump> C:\Dump\test3.ps1
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=DR}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=FIS}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=HQ}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=MAIN}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=NOT_STATED}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=OP}
@{ADDRESS_TYPE=DR} @{ADDRESS_TYPE=FIS} @{ADDRESS_TYPE=HQ} @{ADDRESS_TYPE=MAIN} @{ADDRESS_TYPE=NOT_STATED} @{ADDRESS_TYPE=OP}
CSV Address Type value = OP
XML file AddressType is HQ
NO MATCH. XML value is HQ, Address Type OP
NO MATCH. XML value is HQ, Address Type OP

PS C:\dump>
```

Comment: Your `foreach` loop for the csv file isn't doing anything useful. You could skip that section altogether if you use the `-contains` eg.`if ($address_type_csv.ADDRESS_TYPE -Contains $n)`

Comment: What "provider" are you talking about? Do you want to delete `<OrganisationUnitsRow>` nodes? If they have no matching address type? At least one non-matching address type?

Comment: BenH was right, just changing it to use
    if ($address_type_csv.ADDRESS_TYPE -Contains $n)
was right, now working perfectly